# me pueden explicar como se puede instanciar una clase como propiedad a un objeto del navegador

Tags: javascript

```
window.Modal = class Modal {
constructor(p = {}) {
    if (!window._page) window._page = {};
    if (!window._user) window._user = {};
    if (!window.Modal._element || 
 !document.body.contains(Modal._element)) Modal.restart();

    if (!Modal.Modales) Modal.Modales = {};
```

vi este código de un programador que hizo un modal para una pagina pero mi pregunta es ¿como la clase modal se pude usar como propiedad del objeto window del navegador ?

Comment: si haces `window.otra_propiedad_de_window = "algo"` verás que no hay ningún problema. Sería igual a hacer `var  otra_propiedad_de_window ...`

Comment: y entonces cual crees que fue el propósito del programador para hacerlo de esa manera ?

Comment: la verdad no se. Quiza es para asegurar que `Modal` sea global.